# Watson tts in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-to-speech

[image: Screenshot of an attempt to run code]

Whenever I attempt to run a simple piece of code containing everything I need to run a ttsWatson.play, I am faced with the same errors.

This is my code:

```
from tts_watson.TtsWatson import TtsWatson
TtsWatson = TtsWatson("credentials_here", "more_credentials_here", "en-US_AllisonVoice")
TtsWatson.play("Hello World")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to get acquainted with some points, also it is better to copy the actual error as text in the question.

Comment: Not sure what library that is, but IBM have a supported/maintained Python SDK for Watson Developer Cloud.  https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/python-sdk  . It also has examples.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `dataToRead = ''` with `dataToRead = ''.encode()` in 2 lines.